# Comment replies to be another comment type

Tags: 8, comments

I need the comment replies to be another comment type. So, the normal comments should be of type "Standard". The answers to these standard comments should be of the type "Special", with more fields.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use two different comments you can use only one and hide the "special" fields if the comment is not a reply comment.